# How to have different logger for sub package using log4j.properties

Tags: logging, log4j, tomcat7

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=[%X{username} %d %-5p %F:%L %M()] %m%n
log4j.appender.A1.threshold=INFO
log4j.logger.com.mycompany=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.jsp=INFO
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.calculation.rate.AprCalculation=DEBUG
```

So in the case above i want all the class in com.mycompany to be in INFO mode but anything that is part of AprCalculation class to be in DEBUG mode.

Somehow everything is logging in info mode only.

I don't have any log4j.properties in my tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, the problem was the threshold.

```
log4j.appender.A1.threshold=INFO
```

it needs to be

```
 log4j.appender.A1.threshold=TRACE
```